# comparing a column with itself in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

here is my problem.

I have two tables,

Table1 -

```
id | Name | Code
1  | test | 4
2  | test | 5
3  | test4| 6
4  | test4| 7
5  | test | 8
6  | test | 9
```

Table2 -

```
id | Code
1  | 4
2  | 5
3  | 6
4  | 7
5  | 8
6  | 9
```

Here the **Code** column is the same in the both tables, what I'm trying is, I'm having the **Code** From Table2 AND I'm selecting the other table with it. For example

`SELECT * FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1.Code = Table2.Code WHERE Table2.Code = 4` , that's fine, now I'm getting the results from both tables for the same Code, but now, from that point when I have Table1, I want to get All the rows With the same **Name** . The expected result I want is

```
id | Name | Code
1  | test | 4
2  | test | 5
5  | test | 8
6  | test | 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROm    Table1 t1
WHERE   Name IN (
                    SELECT  t1.Name
                    FROM    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
                            (
                                SELECT  id,
                                        Code
                                FROM    Table2 
                                WHERE   Table2.Code = 4
                            ) t2    ON  t1.id = t2.id
                                    AND t1.Code = t2.Code
                )
```

or even

```
SELECT  *
FROm    Table1 t1
WHERE   Name IN (
                    SELECT  t1.Name
                    FROM    Table2 t2 INNER JOIN
                            Table1 t1   ON  t2.id = t1.id
                                        AND t2.Code = t1.Code
                    WHERE   Table2.Code = 4
                )
```